# Calculate the limit of a function of two variables

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

How to calculate this limit?
$$\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)}\frac{x^2+y^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+9}-3}$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have for $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$:
\begin{align}
\frac{x^2+y^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+9}-3}
=\frac{(x^2+y^2)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+9}-3} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+9}+3}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+9}+3}
=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+9}+3
\end{align}

Hence:
\begin{align}
\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)}\frac{x^2+y^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+9}-3}
=\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)}\sqrt{x^2+y^2+9}+3=\color{blue}{6}
\end{align}

Comment: That was so simple. I didn't think to use the complement of the square root.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**
If you **know** the limit exists and it does not need to be proved, you can take e.g. $y=0$, reducing your limit to
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+9}-3}
$$
and apply L'Hospital's rule.

Comment: We doesn't know for sure that the limit exists.